# Carport post base connector - screws or bolts?

Tags: post, carport

So I plan on using the [Simpson Strong-Tie Model PBS44AZ](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Simpson-Strong-Tie-PBS-4x4-ZMAX-Galvanized-Standoff-Post-Base-PBS44AZ/100374846#) post base. Further below are picture of what the base looks like.

They recommend installing as follows: *Install with 16d common nails, #10 x 1-1/2 in. Strong-Drive SD screws or 1/2 in. diameter machine bolts*

I will be using 5 of these with the 5 pressure treated posts that need replacing. The other side of the carport is attached to the house.

I plan on using either  Strong-Drive SD screws or 1/2 in. diameter machine bolts. Which would you recommend?

Also do these seem rust resistance enough, I hope they will last 40 years?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your profile says you are located "North East".  Is that in the U.S., U.K., Australia, South Africa, etc.?  And is the project located in the same place?

Comment: Yes, the North East US. The footer will be 12" x 48"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found a table to the allowable loads [here](https://www.strongtie.com/castinplacepostbases_postbases/pb-pbs_productgroup_wcc/p/pb.pbs#tables), and it doesn't seem to matter which way they are fastened as long as it used one of the methods per the instructions. I am going to use the Strong-Drive SD screws as they seem to be the easiest to use.